# AttributeError: 'NumberObject' object has no attribute 'indirect_reference'

Tags: python, django, django-views, pypdf

I've been trying to create multiple pdfs and merge them using pypdf (Version 3.7.1). The static data such as images and fonts render out perfectly within the html but don't in pdfs. Following is my code and the error I'm encountering

```
query_set = booklet.objects.filter(booklet_id = id)

combine = []

for i in query_set:
    size = i.size
    
    options = {
        'page-size': f'{size}',
        'orientation': 'Landscape' if i.template_mode == "2" else "Portrait",
        'margin-top': '0mm',
        'margin-right': '0mm',
        'margin-bottom': '0mm',
        'margin-left': '0mm',
        'encoding': "UTF-8",
        'dpi': 900
    }

    url = f"http://ipaddress/test?ids={get_ids}&uuid={i.uuid}&size={i.size}&mode={i.mode}&type_set={i.te_type}&template={i.name}&pre{id.id}"

    pdfkit.from_url(url, output_path=f"{file_path}/pdfs/{i.te_type}_{i.name}_{i.id}_.pdf", options=options, verbose=False)
    combine.append(f"{file_path}/pdfs/{i.te_type}_{i.name}_{i.id}_.pdf")

merger = PdfWriter()

for pdfs in combine:
    merger.append(pdfs)
    pdf_name = "base.pdf"
    merger.write(pdf_name)
    merger.close()

return JsonResponse({"pdf" : pdf_name"})
```

I have tried cnfiguring the nginx file, thinking it could be the case but it is not

I have tried modifying my code and relocating static folder to no success.

I have tried rendering static images into a separate template but as i mentioned above they render in just fine but not in the pdf generated by pypdf

Comment: can you add the full error stacktrace in the question please?

Comment: Please try to make a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - most of the time that enables you to solve the issue yourself. Try to get rid of (1) The Django part (2) the pdfkit part. Don't forget to add all imports. Try to make it reproducible with [public pdf documents](https://github.com/py-pdf/sample-files)

Answer (score 0):

[This closed issue](https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/issues/1898) in the [pypdf GitHub repository](https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf) shows that the `AttributeError: 'NumberObject' object has no attribute 'indirect_reference'` error was fixed. Try to update the pypdf version to [3.17.2](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/3.17.2/), the must updated one by the time I'm writing this answer.